# Drag and drop layer style in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

Is there a way in QGIS to drag and drop style from one layer onto another layer?

I already know two possibilities to copy-paste the style of a layer:

1. Right click on the donor layer, copy its style, right click on the receiver layer, paste the style
2. Set a hotkey in the settings which also works fine

Both solutions work fine, but I think it would be great to be able to copy-paste by drag and dropping.